# MySQL - Select everything from one table, but only first matching value in second table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm feeling a little rusty with creating queries in MySQL. I thought I could solve this, but I'm having no luck and searching around doesn't result in anything similar...

Basically, I have two tables. I want to select everything from one table and the matching row from the second table. However, I only want to have the first result from the second table. I hope that makes sense.

The rows in the `daily_entries` table are unique. There will be one row for each day, but maybe not everyday. The second table `notes` contains many rows, each of which are associated with *ONE* row from `daily_entries`.

Below are examples of my tables;

**Table One**

```
mysql> desc daily_entries;

+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| eid      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| date     | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| location | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Table Two**

```
mysql> desc notes;
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| task_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| eid     | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| notes   | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

What I need to do, is select all entries from `notes`, with only one result from `daily_entries`.

Below is an example of how I want it to look:

```
+----------------------------------------------+---------+------------+----------+-----+
| notes                                        | task_id | date       | location | eid |
+----------------------------------------------+---------+------------+----------+-----+
| Another note                                 |       3 | 2014-01-02 | Home     |   2 |
| Enter a note.                                |       1 | 2014-01-01 | Away     |   1 |
| This is a test note. To see what happens.    |       2 |            | Away     |   1 |
| Testing another note                         |       4 |            | Away     |   1 |
+----------------------------------------------+---------+------------+----------+-----+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Below is the query that I currently have:

```
SELECT notes.notes, notes.task_id, daily_entries.date, daily_entries.location, daily_entries.eid
FROM daily_entries
LEFT JOIN notes ON daily_entries.eid=notes.eid
ORDER BY daily_entries.date DESC
```

Below is an example of how it looks with my query:

```
+----------------------------------------------+---------+------------+----------+-----+
| notes                                        | task_id | date       | location | eid |
+----------------------------------------------+---------+------------+----------+-----+
| Another note                                 |       3 | 2014-01-02 | Home     |   2 |
| Enter a note.                                |       1 | 2014-01-01 | Away     |   1 |
| This is a test note. To see what happens.    |       2 | 2014-01-01 | Away     |   1 |
| Testing another note                         |       4 | 2014-01-01 | Away     |   1 |
+----------------------------------------------+---------+------------+----------+-----+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

At first I thought I could simply `GROUP BY daily_entries.date`, however that returned only the first row of each matching set. Can this even be done? I would greatly appreciate any help someone can offer. Using `Limit` at the end of my query obviously limited it to the value that I specified, but applied it to everything which was to be expected.

Comment: Usually these types of formatting improvements done at the application level (e.g. reporting tools have an option to "Suppress repeating values")

Comment: Can you confirm that you want the most recent row from the second table (if one exists)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, there's nothing wrong with your query. I believe it is exactly what you need because it is returning the data you want. You can not look at as if it is duplicating your `daily_entries` you should be looking at it as if it is return all `notes` with its associated `daily_entry`.

Of course, you can achieve what you described in your question (there's an answer already that solve this issue) but think twice before you do it because such nested queries will only add a lot of noticeable performance overhead to your database server.

I'd recommend to keep your query as simple as possible with one single `LEFT JOIN` (which is all you need) and then let consuming applications manipulate the data and present it the way they need to.

Comment: Thanks. I took your advice and left the query as it is currently written. This data is being fed to a dynamic webpage, so I simply performed the removal of repeating data in that one column in the table in the cgi script. Not sure why I didn't do it this way in the first place, as it was a two minute fix. The other two answers also seemed to return all of the data, like my original query??

Answer (score 1):

Use mysql's non-standard group by functionality:

```
SELECT n.notes, n.task_id, de.date, de.location, de.eid
FROM notes n
LEFT JOIN (select * from 
  (select * from daily_entries ORDER BY date DESC) x 
  group by eid) de ON de.eid = n.eid
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do these queries with explicit filtering for the last row.  This example uses a `join` to do this:

```
SELECT n.notes, n.task_id, de.date, de.location, de.eid
FROM daily_entries de LEFT JOIN
     notes n
     ON de.eid = n.eid LEFT JOIN
     (select n.eid, min(task_id) as min_task_id
      from notes n
      group by n.eid
     ) nmin
     on n.task_id = nmin.min_task_id
ORDER BY de.date DESC;
```